# Can't find reference of Logger

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I have changed the project's framework from 3.0 to 4.0 but I am getting reference error of Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging. I couldn't find any other references. I am using some of this codes in my program:

```
Logger.Write("FaxPro service loop is started.", "FaxProCritical", 0, 0, TraceEventType.Start);
```

Error: The type or namespace name 'Practices' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: do you have a reference to the dlls in your project?  Are the reference to the correct version of the dll?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to make more effort to present your question and with relevant code, using directives, references and versions of dlls.
Seriously, people dont have crystal balls.

I Assume you mean enterprise LIbrary framework.
People re more likely to help when you put effort into the question.

Note:
The newer Versions of Enterprise Library LogWriter is Abstract.  You call LogWriterImpl.
Check your references in the assembly.
What does the fusion log viewer say.  (search how to activate if unsure)